# How can I pass the variables I have placed in the .env file to the containers in my docker swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, docker-swarm, docker-stack

I am trying to use the same *docker-compose.yml* and *.env* files for both **docker-compose** and **swarm**. The variables from the *.env* file should get parsed, via sed, into a config file by running a run.sh script at boot. This setup works fine when using the `docker-compose up` command, but they're not getting passed when I use the `docker stack deploy` command.

How can I pass the variables into the container so that the *run.sh* script will parse them at boot?

Comment: Please share docker-compose files  and full commands  that work or don't work for you. What do you mean by parsing env. vars? You mean using their values?

Comment: Using .env files to parse variables is the **de facto** way to deal with variables. Explaining what parsing and variables are is out of the scope of this question. There is no need to share files since this is a high level question, as that would only muddle the waters.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Actually I found the best/easiest way is to just add this argument to the docker-compose.yml file:

```
env_file:
  - .env
```

Comment: Note this is a different behavior than a `.env` file that expands variables inside the compose yaml file itself. It will inject variables into the environment of the container being deployed. The compose file and deployed container are two different environments.

Answer (score 10):

Loading the `.env` file is a feature of docker-compose that is [not yet supported in `docker stack` commands](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29133). You can manually load the contents of this file in your shell before performing the deploy:

```bash
set -a; . ./.env; set +a
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml stack_name
```

Other options include using docker-compose to pre process the compose file:

```bash
docker compose config >docker-compose.processed.yml
```

Or you could use envsubst to replace the variables to make a compose file with the variables already expanded:

```bash
set -a; . ./.env; set +a
envsubst <docker-compose.yml >docker-compose.processed.yml
```

Note that the `.env` file is different from an `env_file` section of a compose file. The `.env` file is used to expand variables in the compose file itself. The `env_file` declaration for a service injects environment variables into the container.

Comment: I'm not sure this addresses the "docker swarm" component.

Comment: @Octavian first option sources the env and deploys with swarm. Second and third options build a compose file you can deploy with swarm. `docker stack` is a swarm mode command, and the compose yml file is an input to that command.

Comment: This seems like the correct answer, but I can't figure out what the docker-compose.processed.yml is supposed to be.

Comment: The processed file is the compose file with the variables expanded. You deploy that since swarm mode doesn't look at the `.env` file when you deploy a stack with a compose file.

Comment: how come you don't rely on`docker [compose|stack] config` for correct variable expansion?

Comment: @JakobGuldbergAaes `docker compose` didn't exist when this answer was first created, hence the `docker-compose config` that was the only option then. `docker stack config` does not expand variables from `.env` files.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense! Directly no, but it still seems common to keep you env variables in it, source it and use them with config.

Comment: @JakobGuldbergAaes you could just `docker stack deploy` if all you need is `env_file`. That's directly supported with no need to preprocess the compose file.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned the native `env_file` is limited to docker compose BUT there proper way to do it in swarm is to user `docker stack config`

say we have a .env file

```
foo=bar
```

and a compose file

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  myservice:
    env_file:
    - .env
```

Then calling config yields the following

```yaml
❯ docker stack config -c docker-compose.yml
version: "3.9"
services:
  myservice:
    environment:
      foo: "bar"
```

putting it together with deploy we get

```bash
docker stack config -c docker-compose.yml | docker stack deploy -c - mystack
```

docker stack deploy -c <(docker stack config -c docker-compose.yml mystack) mystack

---

If you want to have a variable docker-compose.yml  where you need to interpolate the docker-compose with variables from the .env file you can do this crazy hack

```bash
export $(grep -v '^#' .env-test | xargs) && docker stack config -c docker-test.yml
```

the compose file:

```yaml
---

version: "3.9"

services:
  myservice:
    image: ${THE_IMAGE_NAME}
    env_file: .env
```

the .env file:

```
a=1
THE_IMAGE_NAME=owner/image
```

the output:

```bash
❯ export $(grep -v '^#' .env | xargs) && docker stack config -c docker-compose.yml
version: "3.9"
services:
  myservice:
    environment:
      THE_IMAGE_NAME: owner/image
      a: "1"
    env_file:
    - .env
    image: owner/image
```

Comment: The `.env` file is a different behavior from the `env_file` in `docker-compose` (see the [comment on the downvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58666953/how-can-i-pass-the-variables-i-have-placed-in-the-env-file-to-the-containers-in/58670417?noredirect=1#comment107416399_58701153).

Comment: Hey @Jakob Guldberg Aaes! 
I just wanted to point out that when you declare in the                        
stack-composer.yml file this line "env_file: .env". The .env file does not necessarily need to be on the same path as the stack-composer.yml.  We can also include the path where it can be found. 
Maybe this info can help beginners like me. You did a good job of explaining this matter in a very easy way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To pass shell environment variables through to containers use `env_file` syntax:

```
web:
  env_file:
    - web-variables.env
```

As [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option) state:

> You can pass multiple environment variables from an external file through to a service’s containers with the ‘env_file’ option

However, using `.env` as external filename may cause unexpected results and is semantically problematic.

Placing `.env` in the folder where the `docker-compose` command serves different purpose:

As [Docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file), [Docs2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/), [Docs3](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution) state:

> The environment variables you define here are used for variable
>   substitution in your Compose file
>
> You can set default values for environment variables using a .env
>   file, which Compose automatically looks for

So if compose file contains:

```
db:
  image: "postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION}"
```

You `.env` would contain:

```
POSTGRES_VERSION=4.0
```

This feature indeed works only in compose:

> The .env file feature only works when you use the docker-compose up
>   command and does not work with docker stack deploy

Comment: Thanks for the embellishment, but I believe that the summary of all of that is simply that `docker-compose` _automatically_ searches for the *.env* file, but `docker stack` does not; it has to specified in the _yaml_ file using `env_file:`. My answer was the correct answer; it is an exact answer to my originally posted question.