# docker stack not finding volumes on worker node

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am moving from `docker-compose` to `docker stack`

I am trying to launch my database on my `worker node` from my `manager node` so I am using a `docker-stack.yml` file

on the manager I use command: `docker stack deploy -c docker-stack.yml mr`

I get error:

```
* error decoding 'Volumes[0]': invalid spec: :/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d: empty section between colons
* error decoding 'Volumes[1]': invalid spec: db_data:: empty section between colons
* error decoding 'Volumes[2]': invalid spec: db_logs:: empty section between colons
```

Is there a way in docker stacks to specify to look for those volumes locally to the `worker node` ? also for `.env` files ?

Here is my `docker-stack.yaml`:

```
version: "3.8"
services:

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: "${NGINX_IMAGE}"
    build: build/nginx
    deploy:
      placement: 
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - "${APP_HOST_DIR}/public:/var/www/app/public:ro"
      - "${APP_HOST_LETSENCRYPT}:${APP_CONTAINER_LETSENCRYPT}"
      - "${APP_HOST_NGINX_CONF}:${APP_CONTAINER_NGINX_CONF}"
    networks:
      - central_mr
    depends_on:
      - app

  app:
    container_name: app
    image: "${APP_IMAGE}"
    deploy:
      placement: 
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    restart: always
    build: build/app
    env_file: .env
    networks:
      - central_mr
    volumes:
      - "${APP_HOST_DIR}:${APP_CONTAINER_DIR}"

  dbmr:
    container_name: database
    image: "${MARIADB_VERSION}"
    restart: always
    deploy:
      placement: 
        constraints: [node.role == worker]
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - "${SQL_INIT}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
      - "db_data:${MARIADB_DATA_DIR}"
      - "db_logs:${MARIADB_LOG_DIR}"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "${MYSQL_DATABASE}"
      MYSQL_USER: "${MYSQL_USER}"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - central_mr

volumes:
  db_data:
  db_logs:


networks:
  central_mr:
```

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate. If I missed something, tag me here with an explanation so I can reopen.

Comment: @BMitch it is not the same; the question you linked is asking on the local machine; I am asking on a remote worker

Comment: please reopen or tell me why Im wrong

Comment: The error messages shown all point to your variables not being defined. I'm assuming from the question that those variables are defined in your `.env`.  Did you define them some other way?

Comment: Also, make sure the `.env` file is in the working directory where you run the `docker stack deploy` command.

Comment: Yes I understand but the .env is on the worker node; I have a different .env on my manager. I need the service to look for .env on the machine it is running onto. Same for volumes

Answer (score 0):

> the .env is on the worker node; I have a different .env on my manager. I need the service to look for .env on the machine it is running onto. Same for volumes

This isn't supported. First, I'm not sure the `.env` file will be parsed (it wasn't last time I checked). So to expand variables inside of the compose file, you need to [source those variables yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58666953/596285) where you run the stack deploy command:

```bash
set -a; . ./.env; set +a
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml stack_name
```

That does not expand the values from the files on the workers. There will only be one state for the service and containers deployed on workers, with one exception.

A few of the fields support [service templates](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#create-services-using-templates) which allow you to set fields like an env variable or volume mount, using templates like `{{.Node.Hostname}}`.